# C# - Compiler error CS1503 - Cannot convert from Dictionary, ICollection, List, HashSetr

Tags: c#, lista, .net, collection

He diseñado un `Dictionary` de clave(`string`) a una `ICollection`, que puede ser una `List` o un `HashSet`. Ambas son colecciones `string`, incluso la clave del diccionario es un `string`.

He intentado crear un método genérico para añadir a una determinada clave del diccionario, un determinado elemento a la colección. Pero ni siquiera ha sido posible compilarlo.

El problema no parece estar en la definición genérica de la colección, sino en la declaración del diccionario y de la colección. No puedo continuar y no detecto qué estoy haciendo mal. Necesito ayuda. Este es el código:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// NO COMPILE ERROR CS1503
void AddToCollection<T,U>(U item, U key, Dictionary<U, ICollection<U>> dict)
     where T : ICollection<U>, new()
{
    if (key is not null) dict[item] = new T(){item};
    else dict[key].Add(item);
}

var diccHS = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
var diccLIST = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
// This two sentences DOES NOT COMPILE
AddToCollection<HashSet<string>, string>("item1", "item", diccHS);
AddToCollection<List<string>, string>("item1", "item", diccLIST);

// COMPILE OK - HERE THE CAST COMPILE
void test<T,U>( ICollection<U> col) where T : ICollection<U>, new() { var hs2 =  new T(); }
var hset1 = new HashSet<string>{"hh"};
var list1 = new List<string>{"hh"};
test<HashSet<string>, string>(hset1);
test<List<string>, string>(list1);
```

A ver si podéis echarme una mano.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Para que funcione, tuve que modificar tu código original.

Queda en [este repositorio en github](https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/tree/main/008-collections) como ejemplo [mira la parte de tests para ver los ejemplos](https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/blob/main/008-collections/008-collections-tests/CollectionHelperTest.cs) asi lo puedes ejecutar (se encuentra en NET6 el proyecto)

- [fernandezja/net6-experiments/tree/main/008-collections](https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/tree/main/008-collections)

El código genérico lo encapsule en un "helper", modifique

1. El parametro *Dictionary<U, ICollection> dict* lo modifique por **Dictionary<U, T> dictionary** porque *T* ya es del tipo que se definio (el tipo de ICollection.
2. Además la verificación de que se encuentra o no ya la key de la lista  lo realice con el metodo [ContainsKey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=net-5.0)

Ejemplo [CollectionHelper](https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/blob/main/008-collections/008-collections-console/CollectionHelper.cs)

```
public static class CollectionHelper
{
    public static void AddToCollection<T, U>(U item, 
                                             U key,
                                             Dictionary<U, T> dictionary)
        where T : ICollection<U>, new()
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
            dictionary[key] = new T();
        }

        dictionary[key].Add(item);
    }

}
```

Y para poder probar [aquí los tests que utilice](https://github.com/fernandezja/net6-experiments/blob/main/008-collections/008-collections-tests/CollectionHelperTest.cs)

```
public class CollectionHelperTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void AddToCollection_List_OneValue()
    {
        var dictionaryList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        var listKey = "list 1 key";

        CollectionHelper.AddToCollection<List<string>, string>("item 1 value",
                                                               listKey,
                                                               dictionaryList);

        
        Assert.Single(dictionaryList);
        Assert.Single(dictionaryList[listKey]);
        Assert.Equal("item 1 value", dictionaryList[listKey][0]);

    }

    [Fact]
    public void AddToCollection_List_MultiplesValues()
    {
        var dictionaryList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        var listKey = "list 1 key";

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            CollectionHelper.AddToCollection<List<string>, string>($"item {i} value",
                                                               listKey,
                                                               dictionaryList);
        }

        Assert.Single(dictionaryList);
        Assert.Equal(10, dictionaryList[listKey].Count);
        Assert.Equal("item 1 value", dictionaryList[listKey][0]);
        Assert.Equal("item 10 value", dictionaryList[listKey][9]);

    }


    [Fact]
    public void AddToCollection_HashSet_OneValue()
    {
        var dictionaryList = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

        var listKey = "list 1 key";

        CollectionHelper.AddToCollection<HashSet<string>, string>("item 1 value",
                                                               listKey,
                                                               dictionaryList);


        Assert.Single(dictionaryList);
        Assert.Single(dictionaryList[listKey]);
        Assert.Equal("item 1 value", dictionaryList[listKey].First());

    }

    [Fact]
    public void AddToCollection_HashSet_MultiplesValues()
    {
        var dictionaryList = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

        var listKey = "list 1 key";

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            CollectionHelper.AddToCollection<HashSet<string>, string>($"item {i} value",
                                                               listKey,
                                                               dictionaryList);
        }

        Assert.Single(dictionaryList);
        Assert.Equal(10, dictionaryList[listKey].Count);
        Assert.Equal("item 1 value", dictionaryList[listKey].First());
        Assert.Equal("item 10 value", dictionaryList[listKey].Last());

    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: Super buena respuesta! Además con xUnit! Muchas gracias. Aunque yo pase una key que existe, el cambi que haces me parece correcto.

Comment: Hola, que hace el atributo [Fact] sobre los metodos?

Comment: José... Cuál era el error de OP?

Comment: @Japv el atributo Fact es de xUnit para definir un metodo de test. Podes ver [mas info aqui](https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/netfx/visual-studio). Cree un proyecto de test en vez de realizar codigo en una consola para probar.

Comment: @Arriel "OP"? no entendi? pero lo unico que realice que si era un error fue el tipo de parametro que recibia no era generico (el el punto 1 que comente)

Comment: Disculpa por usar el slang... 'OP' generalmente significa "Original Poster". Me refiero a la persona quien escribió la pregunta. Te hice el comentario porque no veo clara la explicación de la causa del error. Sí nos estás diciendo lo que hiciste, pero no nos dices *por qué* lo hiciste.

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez, ok, gracias